# Why these two strings aren't equal in Dart even though these are exactly same

Tags: flutter, dart

Following strings are exactly same visually & is equal in Python, JavaScript, Java & Go. But not equal in Dart-lang only. I clearly have no idea WTH is going on!!!

```dart
void main() {
  print("the kid laroi" == "the kid laroi");
}
```

I checked their utf8 & ASCII character codes but all are same

UTF8:

- `the kid laroi` -> `\x74\x68\x65\x20\x6b\x69\x64\x20\x6c\x61\x72\x6f\x69`
- `the kid laroi` -> `\x74\x68\x65\x20\x6b\x69\x64\x20\x6c\x61\x72\x6f\x69`

ASCII:

- `the kid laroi` -> `116 104 101 32 107 105 100 32 108 97 114 111 105`
- `the kid laroi` -> `116 104 101 32 107 105 100 32 108 97 114 111 105`

Here's the Dart-pad URL for LIVE preview: https://dartpad.dev/?id=58dad7c825064440b40f6e8df48a74e2

Comment: Running your DartPad prints `true` for me, indicating that the strings *are* equal.

Comment: The link also shows true.

Comment: Well, the Github gist probably messed it up I'll be sharing a screenshot soon